# Commas making a sentence seem choppy

Tags: punctuation, commas

Imagine my surprise, then, when, one Saturday, she agreed to go on a hike with me.

'Then' needs a comma on either side of it because it is an aside, and I think 'one Saturday' needs commas because it is an inserted element, but the result seems strange to me. Are all of these punctuation marks strictly necessary?

Comment: i am good on use of english but not a punctuation expert. so I proffer in comment form: "Imagine my surprise then, when one Saturday she agreed to go on a hike with me."

Comment: Personally I would simply eliminate the commas after "when" and "Saturday".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, all of those commas are necessary for (basically) the reasons you stated. For a quick sanity check, say the sentence out loud! All the pauses indicated by the commas fit.

But it really is a stilted way of getting the idea across. If the real answer you're looking for is how to make this sentence less awkward, try rephrasing it in a way that doesn't require the multiple interjections. Of course, the way you rephrase it might depend upon the larger context of the full paragraph. For a trivial example, let's say that your original paragraph is something like:

> I always thought she hated long walks, hated Saturdays, and hated me. **Imagine my surprise, then, when, one Saturday, she agreed to go on a hike with me.**

Rephrasing your sentence is easy, given a first sentence to flow from:

> I always thought she hated long walks, hated Saturdays, and hated me. **So imagine my surprise when, one Saturday, she agreed to go on a hike with me.**

Short answer: Yes, it's grammatically correct. Yes, it's awkward. No, you don't have to do it that way.

Comment: In other words, there can be more than one correct answer.

Comment: I am curious that you say the original sentence is grammatically correct. Could you explain why if you think this version is missing any commas that would be required for formal writing?  **So, imagine my surprise when she agreed one Saturday to go on a hike with me.**

Comment: @RossMurray Actually, I'm not sure you need the comma after "So". Yours is another example of rephrasing the sentence from the original; in your case, you've moved the "one Saturday" interjection to later in the sentence. As it's still an interjection, it still needs to be set apart by a pair of commas. To remove the commas entirely, perhaps try something like: "So imagine my surprise when she agreed to go on a hike with me one Saturday." But then you kind of lose the emphasis on that one Saturday, which might not be desirable.

Comment: I agree the comma after 'So' not needed. My reason for moving 'one Saturday' is that it becomes an adverbial phrase rather than an interjection when placed after the verb it modifies, so then, no longer needs commas.

Comment: @EightyEighty moving the "one Saturday" changes the meaning from the agreement being made that Saturday, to the hike being on the Saturday. Which *could* be different :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with this statement in the answer by @EightyEighty:

> say the sentence out loud! All the pauses indicated by the commas fit.

That, in my opinion, places the cart before the horse.

- A comma in a correctly punctuated sentence **does** indicate a pause is required when the sentence is read out aloud.
- A pause when a sentence is read out aloud **does not** indicate a punctuation mark is required for the sentence to be correctly punctuated.

Comment: I agree with your bullet points, though I'm interested in your source for them. That's why I called it "a quick sanity check" and not "the rule you must follow".

Comment: Fair enough. It took me some time to correct that commonly held misperception in my thinking when I started writing seriously. I trust you understand why I felt the need to warn ESL learners that thinking that way is a pathway to horridly stilted writing. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide any sources. It is the result of a couple of years of very hard work, but sadly, I still consider myself a "work in progress":.

Comment: Ha! "Work in progress" pretty much sums myself up as well. Good luck out there.

Comment: For examples of wonderfully well pronounced punctuation, see (well, hear) Gerard Hoffnung's delivery of "letter requesting sick leave" from an Oxford Union address.

Comment: Apologies for the unintentional punnage.

Comment: @WillCrawford Thanks for your comments. Great catch, btw, about meaning change if 'one Saturday' was moved to the end. I'm heading off now to read answers to the question _The Royal Order of Adverbs_. I hope that won't become as much of a nightmare to get my head around as the one for adjectives.